# Navigating to a page in a dotnetnuke portal from na external site

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a DNN portal (dnn 7x) and i need to be able to  call an aspx page from the portal directly from an outside source

i.e
http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx

I have created the page and put it at the root folder of the dnn installation. 
Tried to add a friendly url for the page but again i cant access the page i keep gatting 404 error msg
Should i declare hte page in the IIS?
What should i do in order to have access to this page??

Comment: If I understand correctly - you are adding your own aspx page to the root.  But DNN is setup to run all aspx page calls through the pipeline - and because your page isn't really part of DNN it won't show.  Why can't you just create your page within a dnn page?  If it's data access or something -you could use the DNN WebApi as part of a module - or even create a handler to call off to

Comment: I had no problems dumping an .aspx page inside dnn root folder and i would be able to access the page by just calling it www.example.com/mypage.aspx . I cant understand why this is not possible in my current dnn installation so i was wondering if there were any permission configurations that im not aware of that block this function in my current installation